# How to configure handling of when logs sometimes don't exist? fluentd

Tags: fluentd

I am adjusting our fluentd configuration to include a specific log file and send to S3. The issue I am trying to wrap my head around is this.... Only some instance types in our datacenter will contain this specific log. Other instances will not (because they are not running the app that we are logging). How do you modify the configuration so that fluentd can handle the file existing or not existing?

So in the below example Input, this log file will not be on every server instance -- that is expected. Do we have to configure the security.conf file to look for this and skip if missing? Or will fluentd just not include what it doesn't find?

```
## Inputs:
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/myapp/myapp-scan.log.*
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/myapp-scan.log.pos
  tag s3.system.security.myapp-scan
  format none
</source>
```

Comment: How about you just run it and observe the behavior? You might want to take a look at [`refresh_interval`](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#refresh_interval) also.

Comment: @type tail worked perfectly - thank you everyone